# alias a hash element in perl

Tags: performance, perl, reference, alias, copy-on-write

Is it possible to access the same value under different hash keys?  How can I tell Perl not to copy the "very long text?"

```
$hash->{'key'} = 'very long text';
$hash->{'alias'} = $hash->{'key'};
```

Comment: This sounds very much like an XY Problem. You are trying to solve a problem using aliases, but most likely there is a better solution to that problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simple way is to use a reference to a common variable.

```
my $hash;
my $val = 'very long text';
$hash->{key} = \$val;
$hash->{alias} = $hash->{key};

say ${ $hash->{key} };        # very long text
say ${ $hash->{alias} };      # very long text

${ $hash->{key} } = 'some other very long text';

say ${ $hash->{key} };        # some other very long text
say ${ $hash->{alias} };      # some other very long text

say $hash->{key} == $hash->{alias} ? 1 : 0;  # 1
```

The complicated way is to use [Data::Alias](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Data%3a%3aAlias).

```
use Data::Alias qw( alias );

my $hash;
$hash->{key} = 'very long text';
alias $hash->{alias} = $hash->{key};

say $hash->{key};        # very long text
say $hash->{alias};      # very long text

$hash->{key} = 'some other very long text';

say $hash->{key};        # some other very long text
say $hash->{alias};      # some other very long text

say \$hash->{key} == \$hash->{alias} ? 1 : 0;  # 1
```

Comment: I guess it will create some circular references, isnt Scalar::Util's weaken is needed? (first example)

Comment: @soulSurfer2010, Two scalars holding references to a third is not a circle.

Answer (score 5):

[Tie::AliasHash](https://metacpan.org/module/Tie%3a%3aAliasHash) will work, though I wouldn't reccommend going this route. What are you trying to do that you feel you need to alias hash keys? There's likely a better route to go.

Comment: +1; found it surprising that no one mentioned `Alias` modules before. )

Comment: Because you usually do not need the extra module. You have to read the docs and have to install it. What benefit do I gain by using it instead of a quick and easy reference? Besides even the author suggests to use it with care..

Answer (score 2):

use array ref instead of scalar.

```
use Data::Dumper ;

my $Var = [10];
my %Hash = ('k' => $Var, 'a' => $Var);

print Dumper \%Hash;
$Hash{'a'}[0] = 'test' ;
print Dumper \%Hash;
```

Answer (score 1):

No. Following workarounds are possible:

#### Just copy it

Unless we are talking about megabytes over megabytes of data, or unless we are doing this a few thousand times, just copying the data around won't hurt too much.

#### Using references

```
my %hash = (key => 'very long text');
my $reference = \($hash{key});

print "The very long text is ", $$reference, "\n";
```

or

```
$hash{alias} = \($hash{key});

print "The very long text is ", $$hash{alias}, "\n";
```

Drawback: you have to use different syntax.

#### Using variables as keys

```
my $key = "key";
my $alias = $key;

my %hash = ($key => 'very long text');

print "The very long text is ", $hash{$alias}, "\n";
```

Drawback: extra vars.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a reference:

```
$hash->{'key'} = 'very long text';
$hash->{'alias'} = \$hash->{'key'};
print ${$hash->{alias}}, "\n" if ref $hash->{alias};
```

Comment: No, you can't: perl -MData::Dumper -E "$hash->{key} = q/very long text/; $hash->{'alias'} = \$hash->{'key'}; print Dumper $hash; $hash->{alias} = q/something else/; print Dumper $hash;"

Comment: @Oesor That's because you overwrite the reference in `$hash->{alias}` with a string.

Comment: @TLP: Yes, I know. That's my point. It doesn't behave as you would expect from an 'alias' unless you know perl internals a bit better than someone asking the question in the OP would know. It'll work for reads, and the next question is going to be "I tried changing the value using the alias and now I have this bug because there's a mismatch between the two values, help me"

Comment: @Oesor, you can check if it is a ref and handle it differently

Comment: @perreal: Yes, you can. Now you're writing scaffolding code that tests if your alias is a reference or the real value and you've got two problems.

Comment: you might as well store everything as a reference and treat them all the same

Comment: @Oesor No. You can still assign to the reference, you just have to use the proper syntax: `${$hash->{alias}} = q/something else/`. You can't adjust your answer to the OP's perl proficiency. You *can* use references, it's just not a very good idea.

Comment: @TLP: We're both agreed on it being a bad idea. IIRC, you still need to use different syntaxes to write to both the alias and key, tests to figure out what the value is before writing, all sorts of messy referencing stuff I don't know off the top of my head cause I don't deal with doing this sort of thing by choice. ;)

Comment: @Oesor It's certainly a complicated way to solve a problem, and asking for trouble.

Answer (score 0):

#### Use Hash::Util::hv_store

The standard [Hash::Util](https://perldoc.perl.org/Hash::Util) module includes the [hv_store()](https://perldoc.perl.org/Hash::Util#hv_store) subroutine which can be used to alias hash values together. It uses references, but you can access elements with normal syntax, without needing an extra scalar dereference like the previous answers.

This example uses hv_store() to alias some keys together, then changes a couple values and uses Devel::Peek to demonstrate that the aliases still point to the same values as each other.

```perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use Hash::Util;
use Devel::Peek; # only for demonstration; not required to use aliases

# this utility sub turns each pipe-separated list of keys into aliases to
# the same scalar value, within the hashref provided in the first argument
sub alias_keys {
    my $href = shift;
    while (@_) {
        my ($aliases, $value) = splice @_, 0, 2;
        for my $key (split /[|]/, $aliases) {
            Hash::Util::hv_store(%$href, $key, $value) or die;
        }
    }
}

# here a hash is initialized, then some aliases are assigned, and then a
# values are changed, to show that other aliases refer to the new value
my %hash = ('default' => 2, 'n' => 1);
alias_keys(\%hash,
    'dryrun|test|n' => 0,
    'pidfile|p' => '/var/run/sample'
);
$hash{'option'} = 1;
$hash{'p'} = '/var/run/changed';

Devel::Peek::Dump(%hash, 10);
```

(The output here is unavoidably dense.) Note that the aliased keys `dryrun`, `test` and `n` all refer to the same scalar value at `0x800e5f4c8`, and the other aliased pair `pidfile` and `p` refer to a shared value at `0x800e5cb88`. The code uses `%hash` with normal syntax, but changing the value of one aliased key is visible when accessed by another name. In these examples, the `$hash{n}` and `$hash{pidfile}` values are seen with new values propagated from their aliases.

Contrast those with the non-aliased keys `default` and `option`, which have unique SV locations, and a telltale reference count of 1. This shows that even with some aliased keys, the hash continues to work normally, without the extra syntax that would be required to use references explicitly.

```
SV = PVHV(0x800e21ce0) at 0x800e5f378
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (SHAREKEYS)
  ARRAY = 0x800e4da80  (0:9, 1:7)
  hash quality = 175.0%
  KEYS = 7
  FILL = 7
  MAX = 15
  Elt "default" HASH = 0x71c7e975
  SV = IV(0x800e1f668) at 0x800e1f678
    REFCNT = 1
    FLAGS = (IOK,pIOK)
    IV = 2
  Elt "pidfile" HASH = 0xf60020c7
  SV = PV(0x800e27e90) at 0x800e5cb88
    REFCNT = 2
    FLAGS = (POK,IsCOW,pPOK)
    PV = 0x800ff0440 "/var/run/changed"\0
    CUR = 16
    LEN = 18
    COW_REFCNT = 1
  Elt "test" HASH = 0xb6316ff9
  SV = IV(0x800e5f4b8) at 0x800e5f4c8
    REFCNT = 3
    FLAGS = (IOK,pIOK)
    IV = 0
  Elt "p" HASH = 0x1009461a
  SV = PV(0x800e27e90) at 0x800e5cb88
    REFCNT = 2
    FLAGS = (POK,IsCOW,pPOK)
    PV = 0x800ff0440 "/var/run/changed"\0
    CUR = 16
    LEN = 18
    COW_REFCNT = 1
  Elt "n" HASH = 0x3751d09c
  SV = IV(0x800e5f4b8) at 0x800e5f4c8
    REFCNT = 3
    FLAGS = (IOK,pIOK)
    IV = 0
  Elt "dryrun" HASH = 0xe4c9ad9e
  SV = IV(0x800e5f4b8) at 0x800e5f4c8
    REFCNT = 3
    FLAGS = (IOK,pIOK)
    IV = 0
  Elt "option" HASH = 0x3e940e4f
  SV = IV(0x800e1f980) at 0x800e1f990
    REFCNT = 1
    FLAGS = (IOK,pIOK)
    IV = 1
```

It looks like hv_store() has been in Perl core since 5.8.9. I found this technique useful with [Getopt::Long](https://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt::Long), which allows option name aliases, but only stores the value in the first provided key. By aliasing the different variations to the same scalar value, I could refer to option names in the code in the same manner as on the command line.